How to skip an unskippable video on a webpage?
I used to have no problem using a certain script to skip an unskippable video on a training website. However, somehow the script doesn't work on some websites, and the video continues normally.
How can I solve this?
Or
Is there a script that will work on all web pages?
Here is the script I used:
let boring = document.querySelector('video');
boring.currentTime = boring.duration
I tried that script on some website and still works fine, but it doesn't work for some certain website.
I need to know how to solve that.
